# Is it good to pass admob-clicks through a server to avoid invalid traffic?

Tags: android, admob, ads

my admob is getting limited repeatedly for "invalid traffic". I'm using admob in an app which is currently on Play Store. I tried my best to avoid accidental-clicks and used test ads when appropriated. But I believe that somebody maybe trying to sabotage my admob account. I also heard that Google Admob is not blocking invalid traffic itself, instead it is imposing developers to face it (Im not sure either).
So I got two ideas:

1. When user clicks an ad, it should transfer him to a server which counts clicks from specific ip-address and limits/blocks them on suspicious activity.

But Im doubtful if it is possible or it is not violating admob policies.

2. To implement click-counter at client-side and don't load more ads maybe after 2-3 clicks.

But I think it might be still vulnerable in both cases if somebody manages to get ad-unit-ids and creates script to generate invalid-clicks. (I think admob atleast can catch traffic from unauthorised app as I have attached admob to play store through their dashboard).

Comment: I'm doing something drastic as well. I'm disabling clicks on Banner Ads. IN essence, just use them as Impressions. I'm in day 2 of my account suspension so I can't know how it gonna be.